# CMake exclude files from a given pattern after file(GLOB_RECURSE)

Tags: cmake, pattern-matching

I have an little library which has an file structure like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
LibFoo/
  Foo.h
  FooWin.cpp
  FooWin.inl
  FooPosix.cpp
  FooPosix.inl
```

And when i have to build the library in a specific OS (for example Windows) they should contain in the list before using file(GLOB_RECURSE) using a macro:

```
macro( add_recursive dir retVal)
file( GLOB_RECURSE ${retVal} ${dir}/*.h ${dir}/*.cpp ${dir}/*.c ${dir}/*.inl )
endmacro()
```

and my excluding pattern is like this (when Windows is the build host): `*Posix.*` but doesn't work, i tried with this approach:

```
macro( add_recursive dir retVal pattern)
file( GLOB_RECURSE ${retVal} ${dir}/*.h ${dir}/*.cpp ${dir}/*.c ${dir}/*.inl EXCLUDE PATTERN "${pattern}")
endmacro()
```

but the POSIX files still here anyways, CMake doesn't report an error or anything suggested about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `EXCLUDE` option for `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` command flow. You probably take this option from `file(COPY|INSTALL ...)`, which is a different command flow.

You may iterate over list, obtained from `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` and exclude needed files manually:

```
macro( add_recursive dir retVal)
    # Store unfiltered list of files into temporary list
    file( GLOB_RECURSE _tmp_list ${dir}/*.h ${dir}/*.cpp ${dir}/*.c ${dir}/*.inl )
    # Resulted list is initially empty. Copy all needed elements into it.
    set(${retval})
    foreach(f ${_tmp_list})
        if(NOT f MATCHES "Posix.")
            list(APPEND ${retVal} ${f})
        endif()
    endforeach()

endmacro()
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use list filtering to remove items after the GLOB_RECURSE:

```
list(FILTER ${retVal} EXCLUDE REGEX "Posix.")
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code almost worked for me.
cmake nags about the set not having enough arguments and discontinues the macro.
This snippet also makes the extention and exclude filter variable

```
macro( add_recursive retVal dir ext excl)
    # Store unfiltered list of files into temporary list
    file( GLOB_RECURSE _tmp_list ${dir}/${ext})
    # Resulted list is initially empty. Copy all needed elements into it.
    set(${retval} "")
    foreach(f ${_tmp_list})
        if(NOT f MATCHES ${excl})
            list(APPEND ${retVal} ${f})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro( add_recursive )

#example of usage
add_recursive(inc "./" "*.h" "/exclude_folder/")
```